# How can i use ImageNet annotations with images downloaded by links?

Tags: computer-vision, imagenet

I'm new in computer-vision and I can`t understand - is there any way to use not original imageNet images(downloaded from links) together with imageNet annotations which are distributed without any additional access, if not, are there any free labeled visual databases with images of products(cucumber, milk, egg, fish)?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "*not* original imageNet" ? What do you mean by "additional access" ?

Comment: http://www.image-net.org/download-images I can't download images from ImageNet cause I'm not a researcher, i just can 
 have links for them, it's a pitty but annotations(which are open to download) where made on ImageNet pictures

Comment: So, can i use this annotations, or the only way is to relabel images?